# Good Resoures for Learning/Studying GCP

Tags: clinical-study, fda

Are there any *widely accepted* resources out there for studying/learning good clinical practices in the U.S. *outside* of the actual [FDA webpage](http://www.fda.gov/ScienceResearch/SpecialTopics/RunningClinicalTrials/ucm155713.htm) for the matter? Something an entry-level clinical researcher could jump into and make sense of what would you need to know in practice. I see CITI has some courses in GCP and research with human subjects that I'll no doubt take. Something like [this guide on ISO 17025](https://www.unido.org/fileadmin/user_media/Publications/Pub_free/Complying_with_ISO_17025_A_practical_guidebook.pdf) is ideal.

Comment: Ahh ok, some people feel that the question is too broad right now. Might you consider editing it a little to be descriptive of what you're after? That way your good question avoid closing. :)

Comment: Following the edits the question seems clear enough, but there's a remaining problem. It asks for "good" resources, which is a matter of opinion. I think the question can be salvaged by replacing "good" with a more objective measure. Perhaps "widely accepted" would work?

Comment: @CareyGregory - Even "widely accepted" is marginal. This is basically a list question, which *can* make good question/answer pairs *if* the list in question is finite and definitive. This is really neither.

Comment: @JohnP I agree; just looking for something better than "good." This is why some sites (eg, stackoverflow) prohibit questions asking for resource recommendations. They're very often subjective and ephemeral. However, this question fits neither the list of acceptable questions nor unacceptable questions. It's in a gray area, so I would tend to err on letting it stand.

Comment: @CareyGregory - Agreed, which is why I didn't close it already. If a good answer comes up from it, then it's a great resource question. If the community decides it is too ephemeral, then popular vote can close it.